# C++ How do I add commas to the first two items on each line, but not the third in a permutation?

Tags: c++

Write a program that lists all ways people can line up for a photo (all permutations of a list of strings). The program will read a list of one word names into vector nameList (until -1), and use a recursive function to create and output all possible orderings of those names separated by a comma, one ordering per line.

**I have everything right in the output except for the commas, I can get commas after every word, but I only need them after the first two words on each line. I need the output seen in this first image. **

[image]

### Here is my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void AllPermutations (vector<string> &permList, vector<string> &nameList) {
    vector<string> tmpVec; 

    if (nameList.size() == 0) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < permList.size(); i++){
            cout << permList.at(i) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        bool first = true;
        for (auto const& e: nameList) {
           if (first) { first = false; } 
           else { cout << ", "; }
           cout << e;
        
    }
}
    else {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++){
            tmpVec = nameList;

            permList.push_back(tmpVec[i]);
            tmpVec.erase(tmpVec.begin() + i);

            AllPermutations(permList, tmpVec);

            permList.pop_back();
        }
    }
}
int main() {
   vector<string> nameList; 
   vector<string> permList; 

   string name;
   cin >> name; 
    
   while (name != "-1") {
       nameList.push_back(name+","); 
       cin >> name;
    } 

    AllPermutations(permList, nameList); 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What image you are referring ?

Comment: @sujoybyte Incorrect markdown resulted in the image not being displayed; I fixed this...

Comment: Don't add a comma to the names you are adding to `nameList`. Instead, appy them at display time like you're doing in `AllPermutations`. Just print the comma before each item except the first one.

Comment: Why make this harder to reproduce for us than necessary? Use `vector<string> nameList{"Julia", "Lucas", "Mia"};` and remove the loop reading from stdin. Btw: You're iterating through the empty list to print with commas. Also if you make `if (nameList.size() == 1)` the base case, you can avoid the use of the bool variable, but in case the empty list is allowed as input, you need to treat this case separately...

Comment: Also, `std::next_permutation` could be used to produce the permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, it's not pretty but...

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void AllPermutations (vector<string> &permList, vector<string> &nameList) {
    vector<string> tmpVec;

    if (nameList.size() == 0) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < permList.size(); i++){
            if(i+1 == permList.size())
                cout << permList.at(i) << " ";
            else
                cout << permList.at(i) << ", ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        bool first = true;
        for (auto const& e: nameList) {
           if (first) { first = false; }
           else { cout << ", "; }
           cout << e;

    }
}
    else {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++){
            tmpVec = nameList;

            permList.push_back(tmpVec[i]);
            tmpVec.erase(tmpVec.begin() + i);

            AllPermutations(permList, tmpVec);

            permList.pop_back();
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    
    vector<string> nameList;
    vector<string> permList;

    string name;
    cin >> name;

    while (name != "-1") {
       nameList.push_back(name);
       cin >> name;
    }

    AllPermutations(permList, nameList);

    return 1;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Julia
Lucas
Mia
-1
Julia, Lucas, Mia 
Julia, Mia, Lucas 
Lucas, Julia, Mia 
Lucas, Mia, Julia 
Mia, Julia, Lucas 
Mia, Lucas, Julia
```